# Controller returning to current View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So this is simple. I have a view calling a controller, which (depending on a bool) will return a new view. But if not, will stay on the current view.

How will I do this?

My current controller code is something like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult someView(bool myBool) // is really a string
    {
        if (myBool) // Is really checking if the string is empty
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("message", "This is true");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that I need to learn more about mvc4, but please play along ;-D

---

**Edit** *For my Captain Skyhawk^^*

The _Partial page code: (*Thanks to John H*)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someView", "My", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("text")
    <input type="submit" value='send' />
}
```

But the real goal for my question is to find a way to return to the `View` that called it. Hopefully without a `Model` thou it would be the correct way ^^

Comment: Your logic is in the wrong area. What you need is an action link in your page that evaluates the bool and will redirect to a new page if true.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk The logic is wrong yes, but wrong area?  No.  The controller is what dictates which view is presented, not the view itself.

Comment: @John H: Yes, and no. It needs to be in the controller, sure, just not how he is using it. At this point, a GET has already been made and it will return a new page.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: How would you do this? I'm urging you to add an answer which suggest an alternative approach to a solution ^^

Comment: Michael: Could you describe what you are trying to do? I mean, the purpose? I'm guessing you're trying to do some kind of validation?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: On my _Layout page there is a _PartialView which call a Controller. Then I want to decide wither to return to the View that called it or go to a different View

Comment: If you could, please edit your post to show the template call where you're calling "someView". I'll see if I can put something together to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect to a different view:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult someView(bool myBool)
    {
        if (myBool)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("actionname");
    }
}
```

You can also specify the controller name and a pass along stuff to the other action with RedirectToAction's other params

Comment: How would I return to the current View I'm in. Which may be auto-generated, and therefore not the same every time? Which is what I'm looking for

Comment: The return View() part returns the current view. I don't really follow when you say the view is auto-generated. Could you go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish with this auto generated view stuff?

Comment: On my `_Layout` page there is a `_PartialView` which have call a `Controller`. If `myBool` is true it returns to the `View` it called from. If not it goes to a new `View`

Comment: Oh I believe I understand. The someView action can be called from multiple views? So you need to specify which view called it and return that same view? Maybe the someView also takes viewName as a param so you can return that view by name. That seems a little dirty to me though. Googling around gave me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx. With that you can get the url the request originated from which would contain the view name.

Comment: The URL solution is something I already had in mind. It just seems like a awful lot of code to clean the URL to call the right Controller and its method to find the view. But then again, I am asking for a dirty solution

Comment: I mainly work in winforms so this really isn't my specialty but maybe you could override the controller's OnActionExecuting. That gives you an ActionExecutingContext which gives you a RequestContext which contains RouteData.

Answer (score 3):

The `return null` makes no sense.  That's essentially saying "return no view".  Something like this will work:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeView(bool myBool)
    {
        if (myBool)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("message", "This is true");
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherView");
    }
}
```

This is close the `ModelState.IsValid` pattern I mentioned on your other question (which goes something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeView(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // Model is valid so redirect to another action
       // to indicate success.
       return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }

    // This redisplays the form with any errors in the ModelState
    // collection that have been added by the model binder.
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How would I return to the current View I'm in. Which may be auto-generated, and therefore not the same every time?

Comment: See John, that's what I was talking about ;)

Comment: I tend to name my actions in pairs.  For example, one `Create` action which simply displays the form.  The second one which accepts a model, which is populated from the data on the form.  The second action can then return to the original view simply by using `return View(model)`, where `model` is your model which will redisplay your form, including any errors.  That way, you never need to know the name of the view in question.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk I might not always explain myself properly, but I'm glad we're on the same page. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
public ActionResult someView(bool myBool)
{
    if (myBool)
    {
        return View("someView");
      // or return ReddirectToAction("someAction")
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }

 }
```

}